# Multiprocessing works in Ubuntu, doesn't in Windows

Tags: python, windows, multiprocessing, cherrypy, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to use [this example](http://www.defuze.org/archives/198-managing-your-process-with-the-cherrypy-bus.html) as a template for a queuing system on my cherrypy app.

I was able to convert it from python 2 to python 3 (change `from Queue import Empty` into `from queue import Empty`) and to execute it in Ubuntu. But when I execute it in Windows I get the following error:

```
F:\workspace\test>python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 112, in <module>
    broker.start()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 105, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 212, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 313, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 66, in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 59, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: cannot serialize '_io.TextIOWrapper' object

F:\workspace\test>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 100, in spawn_main
    new_handle = steal_handle(parent_pid, pipe_handle)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 81, in steal_handle
    _winapi.PROCESS_DUP_HANDLE, False, source_pid)
OSError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect
```

Here is the full code:

```
# from http://www.defuze.org/archives/198-managing-your-process-with-the-cherrypy-bus.html

import sys
import logging
from logging import handlers

from cherrypy.process import wspbus

class MyBus(wspbus.Bus):
    def __init__(self, name=""):
        wspbus.Bus.__init__(self)
        self.open_logger(name)
        self.subscribe("log", self._log)

    def exit(self):
        wspbus.Bus.exit(self)
        self.close_logger()

    def open_logger(self, name=""):
        logger = logging.getLogger(name)
        logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        h = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
        h.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        h.setFormatter(logging.Formatter("[%(asctime)s] %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s"))
        logger.addHandler(h)

        self.logger = logger

    def close_logger(self):
        for handler in self.logger.handlers:
            handler.flush()
            handler.close()

    def _log(self, msg="", level=logging.INFO):
        self.logger.log(level, msg)



import random
import string
from multiprocessing import Process

class Bank(object):
    def __init__(self, queue):
        self.bus = MyBus(Bank.__name__)
        self.queue = queue
        self.bus.subscribe("main", self.randomly_place_order)
        self.bus.subscribe("exit", self.terminate)

    def randomly_place_order(self):
        order = random.sample(['BUY', 'SELL'], 1)[0]
        code = random.sample(string.ascii_uppercase, 4)
        amount = random.randint(0, 100)

        message = "%s %s %d" % (order, ''.join(code), amount)

        self.bus.log("Placing order: %s" % message)

        self.queue.put(message)

    def run(self):
        self.bus.start()
        self.bus.block(interval=0.01)

    def terminate(self):
        self.bus.unsubscribe("main", self.randomly_place_order)
        self.bus.unsubscribe("exit", self.terminate)


from queue import Empty

class Broker(Process):
    def __init__(self, queue):
        Process.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue
        self.bus = MyBus(Broker.__name__)
        self.bus.subscribe("main", self.check)

    def check(self):
        try:
            message = self.queue.get_nowait()
        except Empty:
            return

        if message == "stop":
            self.bus.unsubscribe("main", self.check)
            self.bus.exit()
        elif message.startswith("BUY"):
            self.buy(*message.split(' ', 2)[1:])
        elif message.startswith("SELL"):
            self.sell(*message.split(' ', 2)[1:])

    def run(self):
        self.bus.start()
        self.bus.block(interval=0.01)

    def stop(self):
        self.queue.put("stop")

    def buy(self, code, amount):
        self.bus.log("BUY order placed for %s %s" % (amount, code))

    def sell(self, code, amount):
        self.bus.log("SELL order placed for %s %s" % (amount, code))




if __name__ == '__main__':
    from multiprocessing import Queue
    queue = Queue()

    broker = Broker(queue)
    broker.start()

    bank = Bank(queue)
    bank.run()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that parts of the `MyBus` object are not picklable, and you're saving an instance of `MyBus` to your `Broker` instance. Because Windows lacks `fork()` support, when you call `broker.start()`, the entire state of `broker` must be pickled and recreated in the child process that `multiprocessing` spawns to execute `broker.run`. It works on Linux because Linux supports `fork`; it doesn't need to pickle anything in this case - the child process contains the complete state of the parent as soon as it is forked.

There are two ways to sole this problem. The first, and more difficult, way, is to make your `broker` instance picklable. To do that, you need to make `MyBus` picklable. The error you're getting right now refers to the `logger` attribute on `MyBus`, which is not picklable. That one is easy to fix; just add `__getstate__`/`__setstate__` methods to `MyBus`, which are used to control how the object is pickled/unpickled. If we remove the logger when we pickle, and recreate it when we unpickle, we'll work around the issue:

```
class MyBus(wspbus.Bus):
    ... 
    def __getstate__(self):
        self_dict = self.__dict__
        del self_dict['logger']
        return self_dict

    def __setstate__(self, d):
        self.__dict__.update(d)
        self.open_logger()
```

This works, but then we hit *another* pickling error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "async2.py", line 121, in <module>
    broker.start()
  File "C:\python34\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 105, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "C:\python34\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 212, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\python34\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 313, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\python34\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 66, in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
  File "C:\python34\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'cherrypy.process.wspbus._StateEnum.State'>: attribute lookup State on cherrypy.process.wspbus failed
```

Turns out`cherrypy.process.wspbus._StateEnum.State`, which is an attribute on the `wspbus.Bus` class inherited by `MyBus`, is a nested class, and nested classes can't be pickled:

```
class _StateEnum(object):
    class State(object):
        name = None
        def __repr__(self):
            return "states.%s" % self.name
```

The `State` object (surprise) is used to track the `Bus` instance's state. Since we're doing the pickling before we start up the bus, we could just remove the `state` attribute from the object when we pickle, and set it to States.STOPPED when we unpickle.

```
class MyBus(wspbus.Bus):
    def __init__(self, name=""):
        wspbus.Bus.__init__(self)
        self.open_logger(name)
        self.subscribe("log", self._log)

    def __getstate__(self):
        self_dict = self.__dict__
        del self_dict['logger']
        del self_dict['state']
        return self_dict

    def __setstate__(self, d):
        self.__dict__.update(d)
        self.open_logger()
        self.state = wspbus.states.STOPPED  # Initialize to STOPPED
```

With these changes, the code works as expected! The only limitation is that it's only safe to pickle `MyBus` if the bus hasn't started yet, which is fine for your usecase.

Again, this is the hard way. The easy way is to just remove the need to pickle the `MyBus` instance altogether. You can just create the `MyBus` instance in the child process, rather than the parent:

```
class Broker(Process):
    def __init__(self, queue):
        Process.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue

...
    def run(self):
        self.bus = MyBus(Broker.__name__)  # Create the instance here, in the child
        self.bus.subscribe("main", self.check)
        self.bus.start()
        self.bus.block(interval=0.01)
```

As long as you don't need to access `broker.bus` in the parent, this is the simpler option.

Comment: Wow, I'm impressed!! Great explanation.

Comment: Mmmh... Does lack of `fork()` in Windows also mean that in order to running a small method of a small class on a large web application with hundreds of classes, the whole shebang will be interpreted  from scratch every time a new process is started? Is it something I should worry about?

Comment: @stenci The `__main__` module of your script will be re-imported in the child, and the entire state of the class you're calling the method on will be pickled and sent to the child. If you've created the other classes inside an `if __name__ == "__main__":` guard (which you should be doing), and your small class doesn't have any references to the other classes, they won't be pickled and sent to or re-imported in the child. The most important thing to remember is to protect stuff you don't want to re-run in the child with `if __name__ == "__main__":`.

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense now (it didn't for a while)