# python multiprocessing pickling/manager/misc error (from PMOTW)

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pickle

I'm having some trouble getting the following code to run on Eclipse via Windows. The code is from [Doug Hellman](https://pymotw.com/3/multiprocessing/communication.html#controlling-concurrent-access-to-resources):

```
import random
import multiprocessing
import time


class ActivePool:

    def __init__(self):
        super(ActivePool, self).__init__()
        self.mgr = multiprocessing.Manager()
        self.active = self.mgr.list()
        self.lock = multiprocessing.Lock()

    def makeActive(self, name):
        with self.lock:
            self.active.append(name)

    def makeInactive(self, name):
        with self.lock:
            self.active.remove(name)

    def __str__(self):
        with self.lock:
            return str(self.active)


def worker(s, pool):
    name = multiprocessing.current_process().name
    with s:
        pool.makeActive(name)
        print('Activating {} now running {}'.format(
            name, pool))
        time.sleep(random.random())
        pool.makeInactive(name)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = ActivePool()
    s = multiprocessing.Semaphore(3)
    jobs = [
        multiprocessing.Process(
            target=worker,
            name=str(i),
            args=(s, pool),
        )
        for i in range(10)
    ]

    for j in jobs:
        j.start()

    for j in jobs:
        j.join()
        print('Now running: %s' % str(pool))
```

I get the following error, which I assume is due to some pickling issue with passing in `pool` as an argument to `Process`.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Eclipse_Workspace\CodeExamples\FromCodes\CodeTest.py", line 50, in <module>
    j.start()
  File "C:\Users\Bob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 105, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "C:\Users\Bob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 223, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\Bob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 322, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\Bob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 65, in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
  File "C:\Users\Bob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
  File "C:\Users\Bob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 939, in reduce_pipe_connection
    dh = reduction.DupHandle(conn.fileno(), access)
  File "C:\Users\Bob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 170, in fileno
    self._check_closed()
  File "C:\Users\Bob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 136, in _check_closed
    raise OSError("handle is closed")
OSError: handle is closed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Bob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 99, in spawn_main
    new_handle = reduction.steal_handle(parent_pid, pipe_handle)
  File "C:\Users\Bob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 87, in steal_handle
    _winapi.DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS | _winapi.DUPLICATE_CLOSE_SOURCE)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied
```

A similar question's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804830/python-multiprocessing-pickling-error) seems to suggest that I initialize `pool` with a function call at the top level, but I don't know how to apply that to this example. Do I initialize `ActivePool` in `worker`? That seems to defeat the spirit of Hellman's example.

Another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30081961/multiprocessing-works-in-ubuntu-doesnt-in-windows) suggests I use `__getstate__`, `__setstate__`, to remove unpickleable objects and reconstruct them when unpickling, but I don't know a good way to do this with Proxy Objects like Manager, and I actually don't know what the unpickleable object is.

Is there any way I can make this example work with minimal changes? I really wish to understand what is going on under the hood. Thanks!

**Edit - Problem Solved:**

The pickling issue was pretty obvious in hindsight. The ActivePool's `__init__` contained a Manager() object which seems unpicklable. The code runs normally as per Hellman's example if we remove `self.mgr`, and initialize the list ProxyObject in one line:

```
def __init__(self):
        super(ActivePool, self).__init__()
        self.active = multiprocessing.Manager().list()
        self.lock = multiprocessing.Lock()
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Comment**:  The 'join()' was in the Hellman example, but I forgot to add it into the code snippet. Any other ideas?

I'm running Linux and it works as expected, Windows behave different read [understanding-multiprocessing-shared-memory-management-locks-and-queues-in-pyt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20742637/understanding-multiprocessing-shared-memory-management-locks-and-queues-in-pyt/24787346#24787346)

To determine which Parameter of `args=(s, pool)` raise the Error remove one and use it as `global`.
Change:

```
def worker(s):
    ...

        args=(s,),
```

---

> **Note**: There is no need to enclose a `multiprocessing.Manager().list()` with a `Lock()`.
>   This is not the culprit of your error.

---

> **Question**: Is there any way I can make this example work with minimal changes?

Your `__main__` Process terminates, therefore all started Processes die at unpredicted position of execution. Add simple a `.join()` at the end to let the `__main__` wait until all Processes done:

```
    for j in jobs:
        j.join()

    print('EXIT __main__')
```

***Tested with Python: 3.4.2***

Comment: I commented out all the lock calls and get the same error. The 'join()' was in the Hellman example, but I forgot to add it into the code snippet. Any other ideas?

Comment: Before I resolved the issue, I made a global semaphore, and a global pool handle, and then ran the code with `args(s, )`, `args(pool, )`, `args(s, pool)`.  All three unfortunately didn't work. The second and third methods resulted in the same error and the first method resulted in `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'makeActive'`.  I made the globals and initialized them like: `pool = None` and
`def initialize_pool():
    global pool \
    pool = ActivePool()`.